# Given these conditions is $f$ of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be bounded on $[a,b]$ and suppose that $TV_{a+\epsilon}^b( f )\leq M$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Does it follow that $TV_a^b (f)$ is finite?

Where $M$ is some nonnegative constant and $TV_a^b (f) = sup_{P} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mid f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) \mid $ where the $P=\{a=x_0, x_1,\ldots, x_n=b\} $ are any partition of $[a,b]$. $TV_a^b (f)$ is called the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$. $f$ is of bounded variation if $TV_a^b (f)$ is finite

It seems like this should be true. I know that
$$TV_a^b (f) =TV_a^{a+\epsilon} (f) + TV_{a+\epsilon}^b (f)$$
So all that needs to be shown is that $TV_a^{a+\epsilon} (f)$ is finite, although I'm having trouble showing this. If this isn't true, are there restrictions that can be put on  $f$ that make this true? Any suggestions?

My Thinking: Informally, 
as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ the interval $[a,a+\epsilon]\rightarrow \{a\}$. So does the $TV_a^{a+\epsilon} (f) \rightarrow TV_a^{a} (f)=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b\}$ be an arbitrary partition of $[a,b]$, and let $\varepsilon=x_1-x_0$, so the partition is $P=\{a,a+\varepsilon,x_2,\dots,x_n=b\}$. Then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|= |f(a+\varepsilon)-f(a)|+\sum_{i=2}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\\\leq |f(a+\varepsilon)-f(a)|+ TV_{a+\varepsilon}^b(f)$$
because $\{x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ is a partition of $[a+\varepsilon,b]$. The terms in the RHS are bounded independently of $\varepsilon$, since $f$ is bounded, and $TV_{a+\varepsilon}^b(f)\leq M$. Therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\leq 2\sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)|+M$$
Since the partition $P$ we started with was arbitrary, we obtain 
$$TV_{a}^b(f)\leq2\sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)|+M<\infty $$

Comment: thanks, so $f$ would be of bounded variation. Would $TV^b_a (f) \leq M$ be true?

Comment: No. Think of the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0<x\leq 1$. Then $TV_{0+\varepsilon}^1(f)=0$, but $TV_0^1(f)=1$.